# How do I access global variables in App_Code directory in ASP.NET Web Application?

Tags: asp.net, variables, global

This is my static class for global variables that I have in my App_Code directory:

```
using System;

public static class GlobalUserInfo
{
public static string Name {get; set;}
public static string Email {get; set;}
public static string Gravatar {get; set;}
}
```

In my master page cs file (MasterPage.master.cs) I have this page load function:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GlobalUserInfo.Email = Request.Form["email"];
    GlobalUserInfo.Name = Request.Form["name"];
}
```

Accessing the data members GlobalUserInfo.Email and GlobalUserInfo.Name like this in Page Load is throwing a Build exception when I try to run it. Commenting out those two lines fixes it. Am I implementing this wrong somehow? I know there isn't a problem with the form request, because inserting the code "string email = Request.Form["email"];" doesn't throw an exception. Any ideas?
I'm building and running this in MonoDevelop on Linux, by the way.

Comment: Is this a Web Application Project, or a Web Site?

Comment: Also, did you realize that these values will be shared across all users of the web site? Every time someone loads a page that uses that master page, these values will be overwritten.

Comment: It's a web application project. Hmm... I did not realize that the values would be overwritten when another user logs in. I guess using the global variables wont do me any good then.

Comment: I think I'll create a dynamic class and create a new object when a user loads the User page instead. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You may want to tell us what you're trying to accomplish.